# Read json until "more" comment

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I want to pull from a tumblr blog and display it on another webpage using javascript.

I'm using the $TUMBLR_BLOG/api/read/json feed which provides a variable filled with the information from the blog post.

I want to print everything up to the `"<!-- more -->"` set of characters in the 'regular-body' section, ie. I don't want to print everything in the 'regular-body' just up to that more section.

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Eg. API read: http://blog.intercut.yegfilm.ca/api/read/json

Eg. Basic code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blog.intercut.yegfilm.ca/api/read/json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// The variable "tumblr_api_read" is now set.
document.write(
'<h3> <a href="' + tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['url'] + '">' + tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['regular-title'] + '</a></h3>' +
tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['regular-body']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // The variable "tumblr_api_read" is now set.
  var url = tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['url'];
  var title = tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['regular-title'];
  var body = tumblr_api_read.posts[0]['regular-body'];
  body = body.substring(0,body.indexOf("<!-- more -->"));

  document.write('<h3> <a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a></h3>' + body);
</script>
```

Simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like `responseData.split("<!-- more -->")[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the `<!-- more -->` and print the substring upto that index.

```
sampleString = "Foo <!-- more --> Bar";

moreIndex = sampleString.indexOf("<!-- more -->");

if (moreIndex > 0) {
  console.log(sampleString.substring(0, moreIndex));
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xeVM/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript `SubString()` method:

**Example**:

```
var mystring = 'Hello World <!-- more -->';
alert(mystring.substring(0,mystring.indexOf("<!-- more -->")));
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/8CXd8/

**Documentation**: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp